# What does "easy time" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm not a native English speaker. I'm reading a news about new HTC smart phone. I don't know what does "easy time" in the following context?

*[Snip: Author is talking about new leaked photos about new HTC One M9 smart phone.]*

> The One M9 leak extravaganza continues.
>
> More HTC One M9 photos leak, show the handset in gold this time
>
> HTC has never had **an easy time** keeping upcoming devices a secret, and
>   that trend seems to be continuing with what is probably the company’s
>   most important flagship smartphone in the last few years. The HTC One
>   M9 has once again made it to the internet in the form of photos that
>   show the back of the gold version of the handset.

Comment: It means it was a tough job for them to keep these secrets. They are insisting on the fact that keeping photos from leaking all over the Net was kinda improbable so they just couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+an+easy+time+of+it) **to have an easy time on it** is an idiom and means:

> to have an experience with something that is less difficult or severe than others have experienced.

So in the context in question it means that HTC has experienced difficulties (great) in keeping upcoming devices a secret.